# React js Сохранение формы при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, запрос, form, get

Подскажите нубу, как можно сделать, что бы при перезагрузке страницы данные в форме сохранялись, т.е. мы вбиаем их в поля, нажимаем кнопку(обработчик шлёт запрос на сервер) (если надо, то добавлю, прошу заранее не надо ругаться, мол не добавил то се). Потом появляется список данных, перезагружаем страницу, форма чистая, но в get запросе данные остаются.
Как можно выбрать данные из get запроса и поставить обратно в форму?
Или можно как-то проще.. Пробывал `split`, получается абракадабра.

```js
class PersonForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {sex: 'female', firstName: '', lastname: '', email: '', phone: ''};
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    const name = event.target.name;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        
        <label>First Name: <input name="firstName" type="text" 
                             value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.onInputChange}/></label>
        <br/>
        <label> Last Name: <input name="lastName" type="text"
                             value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.onInputChange}/></label>
        <br/>
        <label> Email: <input name="email" type="email"
                             value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onInputChange}/></label>
        <br/>
        <label> Phone: <input name="phone" type="tel"
                             value={this.state.phone} onChange={this.onInputChange}/></label>
        <br/>
        <label> Sex: <select name="sex" value={this.state.sex} onChange={this.onInputChange}>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="submit" ></input>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PersonForm />,  document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**UPD.**
@Klimenkomud Вы правы, я не совсем правильно изложил свою мысль, и так у меня есть форма с n-числом полей, все поля разные, пользователь заполняет их, нажимает на кнопку, на экране остаётся эта заполненная форма и отображаются результаты поиска (данные из формы перебираются в get запрос) в результате get запрос выглядит примерно так : "..... /search-car?date_from=&date_to @ ....." .И тут пользователь решает обновить страницу. При обновлении он видит следующие: все поля в форме которые он заполнял стали пустыми. Вот я и пытаюсь забрать данные из get запроса, и положить их обратно в форму.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы столкнулись с проблемой молотка: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy
Я думаю вам нужен несколько другой результат. Объясните, для чего вам это нужно?

Comment: Тогда мой ответ будет вам полезен

Comment: @Klimenkomud Несомненно! Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы всё-же хотите получить данные из `get` параметров, то есть несколько вариантов. Если вы используете `react-router`, то эти данные можно получить из `this.props.location.query.имя_гет_параметра_из_урла` Если же на чистом `js` - можете использовать вот такую функцию:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
  var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

И потом использовать её в конструкторе, определяя `state` компонента:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {sex: getParameterByName('sex') || 'female', ...etc}
}
```

Таким образом, в форму попадут данные из `get` параметров, либо дефолтные.
P.S. Всё-же, дополните ваш вопрос конкретной целью данных "махинаций", возможно вам нужно совсем не это!
P.P.S Источник, откуда взята функция: [Тыць](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)